# MS Access VBA: Word to PDF Conversion - Save as pop up

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I have an MS Access VBA tool. I am incorporating a small code that will convert a particular set of pages to PDF. Everything works fine, except I get this "Saving as" prompt while each new PDF is created.

[image]

Is there a way to disable this prompt.

I have already used `DoCmd.SetWarnings True`. It doesn't help.

Following is my code to convert to PDF:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
oDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strFolderPath & "\" & (a) & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, Range:=wdExportFromTo, From:=FirstPg, To:=LastPg
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: `ExportAsFixedFormat` is invoked using the Word application. `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` only affects what's displayed through Access. I'm not an expert in Word, but you need to look to Word commands to suppress this, not Access ones.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.displayalerts